# Python mysql-double fetching literal for int base 10 error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to receive DOUBLE values from mysql.

I Have this mysql table "fxvalues" structure

```
Y1 -DOUBLE
X1 -DOUBLE
X2 -DOUBLE
...
X8 - DOUBLE
```

Then i run this code on python

```
queryvals=("SELECT Y.col1 as Y1,X.col1 as X1,X.col2 as X2,X.col3 as X3,X.col4 as X4,X.col5 as X5,X.col6 as X6,X.col7 as X7,X.col8 as X8 from fxvalues as Y, (SELECT * from fxvalues where interfaz_id="+str(Y_interfaz_id)+
            " ) as X where Y.interfaz_id="+str(id)+" and Y.day=X.day and Y.year=X.year and Y.month=X.month and Y.hour=X.hour and Y.min=X.min");

cursor2 = cnx.cursor();                                                    
cursor2.execute(queryvals);

for (Y1,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8) in cursor:                
    print("Start");
    #print(str(float(Y1))+"  "+str(float(X1))+"  "+str(float(X2)));


cursor2.close();
```

i receive this message on `for (Y1....) in cursor`:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   b'48.047454833984375'

Any idea??

Comment: you are getting  `b'48.047454833984375'` b also??

Comment: not solved but i replaced for(....) by rows = cursor2.fetchall() and get a rows as i expected...